# How to get index of selected option in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to get the selected option ***index*** of a `select` using Angular. I am using Angular (4) and Ionic 3.

My template looks like below:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="obj.city">
   <ion-option *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index;" 
                [value]="city"  [selected]="i == 0">
                {{city.name}}
   </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

I want the index of selected city to be accessed in Component code. Lets say, I want that index to be assigned to a variable `selectedCityIndex` in component.

My current code is pre selecting the first option as default. Solution should not break this functionality.

I am searching for a solution which do not include interating the array (i.e. no loop in JavaScript part). It should not use "indexOf" method or document's methods like "document.getElementById". I am not using jQuery.

Comment: check my answer. pluker its working now

Comment: A bit unclear to me... where do you want the index? What variable should hold the index?

Comment: is `indexOf` allowed in template though? This seems very tricky, not much seems to be allowed :D

Answer (score 9):

If you want index in the component class file, please check this plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/9Z7jjeSW7fmTUR7SbqNk?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h2>Select demo</h2>
    <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" >
      <option *ngFor="let c of cities;let i = index" [value]="i"> {{c.name}} </option>
    </select>
  `
})

class App {

  public value:integer;
  cities = [{'name': 'Pune'}, {'name': 'Mumbai'}, {'name': 'Nagar'}];
  selectedCity = this.cities[1];

  constructor() {
    this.value = 0;
  }
  onChange(cityindex) {
    console.log(cityindex);
    alert(cityindex);
  }

}


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

After wasting 3 hours, I found a single line java script solution.

you can use `event.target["selectedIndex"] - 1` to get the `selectedIndex` of select.

Example:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" #Code name="Code" [(ngModel)]="model.Code" (change)="searchWithCode($event)" >
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Please select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let x of Codes" [value]="x.Code" [selected]="x.Code == model.Code">{{x.Name}}</option>
</select>



searchWithCode(event:Event) : void {
    let index:number = use event.target["selectedIndex"] - 1;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18842#issuecomment-324399823

Answer (score 1):

Use forEach to iterate based on the value present in `ngModel` as below,

```
this.cities.forEach((city,index) => {
   if(city ==== obj.city){
       selectedIndex= index;
    }
})
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question I do not want to interate over an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `(ngModelChange)` . The (ngModelChange) event listener emits events when the selected value changes.

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <h2>Select demo</h2>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" >
          <option *ngFor="let c of cities" [ngValue]="c"> {{c.name}} </option>
        </select>
      `
    })
    class App {
      cities = [{'name': 'SF'}, {'name': 'NYC'}, {'name': 'Buffalo'}];
      selectedCity = this.cities[1];

      onChange(city) {
        alert(city.name);
      }
    }
```

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/tcnPfCplQbywbBHVsiUy?p=preview

Comment: OP asked for index and not the selcted item.

Comment: [ng-value] is not allowed in <ion-options>. Its throwing errors. "Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-option'."

Comment: use [value]="i" instead of ng-value

Comment: give me you jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: your solution is giving the selected index but you are assigning index to [value] of select which removes city object from [(ngModel)] which further breaking the pre selection of select box

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="obj.city">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index" (ngModelChange)="onChange(i)" [value]="city">
            {{city.name}}
        </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: Your solution is not working on my code. Can you please share a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @YuvrajPatil did you check my plunker?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.